# IP grounding of domain is hidden in sub domain

Tags: dns, spf

We have a sub domain like [www.zz.de](http://www.zz.de) which is found in the DNS records and has got an IP address. On the other hand the main domain zz.de  not have a DNS entry.

How is that possible? Is it an entry to the dark net?

Answer (score 1):

The `www` subdomain isn't in any way required to be the same as the main domain, although it typically is set that way.

So check your domain registrar/DNS provider to see what was added.

You can either add the record again for the naked domain as well, or you might be able (depending on the provider you're using) to do some sort of redirect/forwarding from the naked domain to the www subdomain.

Comment: The problem still is that zz.com does not have an IP address, but is's subdomain  sub.zz.com has got one. This looks very inconsistent and embarrassing.

Comment: What do you mean "still", what have you done already? If it is this way then this is the way it's set.

Comment: I mean that the zz.com dors not habe an IP. That is astonishing.

Comment: If you didn't set it with a DNS record to an IP it would not have an IP, that's expected.